# Instancing a particular number of a sprite

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, instance, ccsprite

In my game, I need to instance a certain number of sprites depending on my game's level. That number of sprites is stored in a .plist file. The way my game works is that it selects a random type of enemy for that one particular level. Then, it goes and finds the level number, and then it finds the amount of sprites it need to instance for that level. This is what my plist looks like:

[image: My Plist]

What I need is a way to instance that amount of sprites, no more, no less. I have some ideas on how the code could work, but as I am new to Objective C, I don't know what the code itself would look like.

Comment: What's your question? 1) How to read the plist file and get the number of instances? 2) How to create a given number of sprites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the number of sprites for a given level like this:

```
- (int)numberOfSpritesForLevel:(int)level
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"plistFileName" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *plist = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSDictionary *levels = [plist objectForKey:@"Mosquito"];
    NSString *levelKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"L - %d", level]; // Or "L-%d" if there is no space in the keys
    return [[levels objectForKey:levelKey] intValue];
}
```

Then you can create the sprites like this:

```
int level = 3; // Or whatever value you need.
int numberOfSprites = [self  numberOfSpritesForLevel:level];
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSprites; i++) {
    // Create a sprite here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm guessing in the "create a sprite here" part, I just put the line of code that i'd usually use to instance a sprite?

Comment: Yes. That line will be executed multiple times, so you will end up with multiple sprites as you expect.

Comment: Also, where do i put the (int) numberOfSpritesForLevel ?

Comment: In the same class where you call it= `int numberOfSprites = [self  numberOfSpritesForLevel:level];`.

Comment: Whats the difference between numberOfSprtiesForLevel and numberOfSprites?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YourPlist" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *plist = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];

//Get the dictionary
NSDictionary *levels = [plist objectForKey:@"Mosquito"];
for(int i = 0; i < [[levels objectForKey:@"L-1"] intValue]; i++){
    //make your sprites
}
```

I'd do something like the above and substitute in for whichever level you're on.